# in Vim key mapping, is there a way to repeat a key for multiple times?

Tags: vim, key-bindings

I want to add quick key macro in vim for fast editing. Something like

```
imap <buffer> <A-S-p> printf("\n");<Left><Left><Left><Left><Left>
```

My question is, is there a **multiply** operand in key mapping? Something like

```
imap <buffer> <A-S-p> printf("\n");<Left>x5
```

Comment: Sure, it’s `<Esc>5hi`.

Comment: @Ryan `<Left>` is `h` not `l`. You can use also `<c-o>5h`.

Comment: Yes, <Esc> is a method. Still want to know if there are key repeating method in insert mode.

Comment: I doubt it. I am not sure but i would be staggered if there is a key repeating method for insert mode. And I personally don't see why there should be, insert mode is for inserting. And as @Meninx-メネンックス said, you could achieve what you try with <c-o>. As far as your example goes, it looks like a job for a snippet plugin.

Comment: If I can ask, what if the mapping is realized on the command line (after :)? For example imap x :something<Left>x5.

Answer (score 0):

Every key in `:help key-notation` needs to be specified on its own. Most *movement commands* (like `h`) take a (prepended, optional) `[count]`, but not `<Left>`.

If you're looking for a way to *type* the mapping faster, stop inserting after the `;`, and then append the following multiple times: <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>L</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>.